# Why is Socket Accept taking approx 1 sec to complete?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

As a part of a task I'm working now I need to create several Tcp/Ip endpoints. I was surprised to realize that this is so slow. Here is an example of code:

```
        var started = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        for (int i = 20000; i < 20050; i++)
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            started.Reset();

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var listener = new Socket(
                        AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                        SocketType.Stream, 
                        ProtocolType.Tcp
                    );
                listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(
                        IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), i)
                    );
                listener.Listen(1);

                started.Set();

                var handler = listener.Accept();

                // here goes work after socket is opened 
                // code omitted for brevity 
            });

            started.WaitOne();

            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Openned in ---> {0}", 
                watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
```

Here is an example of output.

```
    Openned in ---> 73
    Openned in ---> 0
    Openned in ---> 0
    Openned in ---> 570
    Openned in ---> 999
    Openned in ---> 1000
    Openned in ---> 999
    Openned in ---> 998
    Openned in ---> 998
    Openned in ---> 1000
    Openned in ---> 1000
    Openned in ---> 998
    Openned in ---> 998
    Openned in ---> 1000
```

As a part of the test nobody is expected connect yet, which means it blocks at Accept() line. Who can point me to the reason of why this is happening ?

Comment: what do you do in the omitted code?

Comment: @Fredou the omitted code is passing `handler` to another thred

Comment: Why on earth would you use `Task.Run`?!

Comment: @Aron `TaskFactory.StartNew` does the same

Comment: @ruslander That isn't my point. Why are you threading? You know you are using the threadpool with `Task.Run`. You are also timing how long it takes for `Task.Run` to get to the head of the `ThreadPool` queue. Given the first 3 seems to run quickly I can assume you have a quad core PC and the omitted code takes approximately 1 second to run.

Comment: The problem is that you've written code that is concurrent synchronous. That is you have several threads but actually they block each other so its actually slower than single threaded. My point was that if you have access to `Task.Run` then you should be using async await.

Comment: @Aron as a part of application bootstrap i need to start 50 endpoints, each of them lives in its own thread. i need to perform other stuff only after all of them are initialized and waiting for connections. With current code 1 second is too much for what I need

Comment: Threading is NEVER a requirement. Why are you trying to make 50 threads? Does your production server have 50 cores?

Comment: @Aron yes it has 64-Core

Comment: going to leave this here now http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your usage of `Task.Run`. It does not do what you think it does. `Task.Run` does not create a thread. Instead it runs work on a `ThreadPool`. The simplest change to "fix" this is to use `Task.Factory.StartNew(..., TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)` instead.

However it makes much more sense to make usage of async await, unless you are actually working in the HF space, and this is for a trading/real time pricing platform. In which case I really need to stop communicating with you.

Comment: it is gonna be open source now I am prototyping, `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to increase the minimum [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx)

> By default, the minimum number of threads is set to the number of
>   processors on a system. You can use the SetMinThreads method to
>   increase the minimum number of threads. However, unnecessarily
>   increasing these values can cause performance problems. If too many
>   tasks start at the same time, all of them might appear to be slow. In
>   most cases, the thread pool will perform better with its own algorithm
>   for allocating threads. Reducing the minimum to less than the number
>   of processors can also hurt performance.

example;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100,100);

        var started = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        //....
```